# Button value property undefined when using ngFor and accessing it using (click) -Angular 8

Tags: angular

Im trying to set a variable called fecha using the value defined in a dropdown list defined with ngFor.

I first get all of the list values and then iterate on them using ngFor like this

```
<li class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" *ngFor ="let fecha of fechas">
                    <button class="dropdown-item"  type="submit" *ngFor ="let fecha of fechas" (click)= "setFecha(this.value)" value="{{fecha._id}}">{{fecha._id}}</button>
                </li>
```

However when i click on the button the console returns

```
ERROR TypeError: "fecha is undefined"
```

Is there an error when i pass the value to the function or is it a wrong way of accessing the value of the button

Comment: You have two ngFor declarations. They are probably conflicting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing *this* to *fecha*
Also I noticed you have nested for loop, is this intended?

```
<li class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" *ngFor ="let fecha of fechas">
                    <button class="dropdown-item"  type="submit" *ngFor ="let fecha of fechas" (click)= "setFecha(fecha)" value="{{fecha._id}}">{{fecha._id}}</button>
                </li>
```

If nested for loop is not intended, code should look like

```
<li class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" *ngFor ="let fecha of fechas">
   <button class="dropdown-item"  type="submit"  (click)= "setFecha(fecha)" value="{{fecha._id}}">{{fecha._id}}</button>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , i have a question ¿Why does setting the parameter to the object work but not to the property of the html element?

Comment: (click) is an angular command and 'this' keyword means something else in that scope according to angular framework due to using of arrow functions internally (https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/arrow-function) so you must explicitly use model object and not to refer to model (object) as this.. hope this is useful :)

Answer (score 2):

You have ngFor on your li and your button.

Try something like:

```
<li class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" *ngFor ="let fecha of fechas">
   <button class="dropdown-item"  type="submit" (click)= "setFecha(fecha)" value="{{fecha._id}}">{{fecha._id}}</button>
```